# Docker data volume and permission

Tags: docker, pydio

I'm trying to write a Dockerfile file to run Pydio community edition. I've an almost working Dockerfile.

```
RUN mv pydio-core-${PYDIO_VERSION} /var/www/pydio-core
RUN chmod -R 770 /var/www/pydio-core
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/pydio-core/data/files/ /var/www/pydio-core/data/personal/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pydio-core

VOLUME /var/www/pydio-core/data/files
VOLUME /var/www/pydio-core/data/personal
```

This works except that when the container is started for the first time, the access rights of the **files** and **personal** folders is 755 and their owner is not **www-data** but **1000**. So once started, I must connect the container to fix permissions (770) and ownership (www-data) and everything works.

I just wonder if it may have something in my Dockerfile which could explain the problem, or if the issue probably comes from the Pydio source code itself.

Comment: Are you looking at the ownership of the files from the docker host in the /var/www/pydio-core... directories, or in the container itself? if your container is based on an image that has bash you can do docker exec -it <name of container> bash and then navigate to the directory. I'm betting the permissions are correct in the scope of the container, but not the host, which is expected. The container (build) doesn't know anything about the host.

Comment: in the container itself. When it starts, all files and folder are owned by www-data, except *files* and *personal* which are owned by 1000:1000.